# Forms Authentication Cookie not expiring on Server Shutdown/Failure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, session-cookies

Here is a use case of my login using a CustomMembershipProvider

1. User Logs in MembershipProvider validates user account
2. User property of Membership is set to user details coming from the database
3. An authentication ticket is created
4. Forms authentication cookie is added.
5. User is logged in

Here is a use case of my problem

1. Stop whe web development server
2. Start the web development server, and user is still logged in (due to cookie?)
3. User property Membership is set to null due to server restart/failure
4. Application throws exception due to null user value

The only solution I could think off is to clear all cookies on Application_Start() but I don't know how is that even possible as Request is out of context during application start.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this kind of problem?

Here is the code:

**CustomMembershipProvider**

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    #region Unimplemented MembershipProvider Methods
    //Other methods here
    #endregion

    //private IUserRepository _userRepository = new UserRepository();

    //Ninject bindings
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    [Inject]
    public IUserRepository UserRepository
    {
        set
        {
            _userRepository = value;
        }
    }

    private IProfileRepository _profileRepository;

    [Inject]
    public IProfileRepository ProfileRepository
    {
        set
        {
            _profileRepository = value;
        }
    }


    public User User
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Profile Profile
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public CustomMembershipProvider()
    {
        MvcApplication.Container.Inject(this);
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Trim())) return false;

        User user = _userRepository.GetUserByUsername(username);

        user.UserType = UserHelper.GetUserTypeById(user.UserTypeId);

        if (user == null) return false;

        string hash = PasswordHelper.ComputeHash(password, user.PasswordSalt);

        if (user.Password == hash)
        {
            this.User = user;

            Profile profile = _profileRepository.GetProfileByUserId(user.UserId);

            this.Profile = profile;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the login method of the **Account Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
        {

            if (!provider.ValidateUser(username, password))
            {
                TempData["LoginError"] = "Incorrect";
            }
            else
            {
                User user = provider.User;

                if (!user.Verified)
                {
                    TempData["LoginError"] = "Please verify your account";
                    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath);
                }

                //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username,false);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new
                               FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                               username,                    //user name
                               DateTime.Now,                //creation
                               DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), //Expiration
                               false,                       //Persistent
                               username);                   //since Classic logins don't have a "Friendly Name"

                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));

                WebsiteObjects.Profile profile = provider.Profile;


                TempData["LoginError"] = String.Empty;
            }


        return Redirect("/");

    }
```

Suggestions below are not doable because whenever I restart the server here is the case.

1. Request.IsAuthenticated is FALSE on Application_BeginRequest;
2. Request.IsAuthenticated is TRUE on my 'View'

why is this happening?

Comment: Hi, I need more answers regarding my problem :(

Comment: Step 2 you mean the UserData Property of FormsAuthTicket or the something else? Can you share the code.

Comment: I have just included the code I used for my login and membership provider.

Comment: So if I am understanding it correct, you check if Request.IsAuthenticated and User is null then you repopulate it. Yes, it could be Begin_Request. Did you try it and/or did you face any issues?

Comment: User is set to null because it is only populated on my login action. However when the server is restarted the login is not called but authentication still works because of the persisting cookie. If I populate and check it every Begin_Request wouldn't that give me some overhead.

Comment: Did you try Application_AuthenticateRequest event. I think the IsAuthenticated might have not been set in BeginRequest.

Comment: hi gbs, thank you I tried Application_AuthenticateRequest and it works. please post a separate answer, I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Application_AuthenticateRequest check if Request.IsAuthenticated=true but User object is null then re-populate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform step 2 on each request or store the user details into the UserData part of the authentication cookie.

Comment: you mean repopulate the User property of my MembershipProvider on Application_BeginRequest based on some kind of user id from the FormsAuth cookie?